# primaykey and foreign key exception?

Tags: sql-server

i get this error when i inserting the data in a table this is my error

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_playlistvideos_videos". The conflict occurred in database "tpvnew", table "dbo.videos", column 'videoid'.

Comment: The error message is pretty descriptive, don't you think? Or what exactly is your question?

Comment: It would really help if you could show us the INSERT statement that causes this problem and also tell us which database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide a valid key for your foreign key column.

Comment: ya i get that and i solved that problems thank you for response

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the videoid in the new record you insert into playlistvideos actually exists in videos table.

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT into the target table referenced a key that doesn't exist in the foreign table.